# Сокрытие точками ненормативной лексики

Tags: орфография, обсценная-лексика

Пишу статью об оскорблениях в русском языке. Не смог найти информацию, как, согласно существующим нормам, правильно вставлять точки в матерные слова. Зависит ли количество точек от числа сокрытых букв? Только ли в середине слова должны располагаться точки? Пример:

> х.й или х...й

Какой из вариантов верный? Спасибо.

Comment: От числа сокрытых букв? Высоким стилем шпарите?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: @Aer, спасибо, я в курсе, например в Stack Overflow на русском у меня [**22 вопроса — 22 принятых ответа**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b0-%d0%a7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85?tab=questions). Однако в данном случае мне хотелось бы услышать, что пишут по данному поводу авторитетные источники по теме. Как будет время и желание, например, [**здесь**](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/q/172/180507) могу расписать подробно свою позицию. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Таких правил нет, да их и быть не может, как можно нормировать ненормативное? 
Разве Госдума опять чего-нибудь отчебучит.

В принципе, я думаю, тут используется тот же принцип (опять-таки ненормируемый), как при воспроизведении плохочитаемого текста. Где не читабельно - там и отточия. Хоть в начале слова, хоть в конце. Количество точек, естественно, всегда равно трем.

Ну и конечно, каждый издатель волен устанавливать свои правила. Хозяин — барин.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы пишете научно-популярную статью, почему бы не оставлять слова такими, как они есть? «Прикрывая» их, вы показываете, что стыдитесь их использовать, что нарушаете таким образом табу на их использование. Именно этот факт и делает их использование «пошлым». Поэтому я считаю, что, если вы относитесь к предмету статьи серьёзно и цель вашей статьи не в том, чтобы вызвать стыд или возмущение, вы должны писать слова как есть, целиком.

В качестве аналогии: быть голым на общественном пляже — неприлично; быть голым на нудистском пляже — нормально. Для нудистов нагота не является табуированной и поэтому не может быть неприличной.

Answer (score 2):

Формальных правил на эту тему не встречал.

Однако хочу заметить: наблюдаю, что помимо устоявшегося годами в "бумажной" литературе (книги, журналистика) способа скрытия мата точками в неформальном интернет-общении набирает популярность способ сокрытия мата при помощи замены одной из букв на знак '@' или '#'.

Способов много: можете выбирать тот, который вам нравится.