# Можно ли задать вопрос о правописании некоторых русских матерных слов?

Tags: орфография, лексика, обсценная-лексика

Правописание матерного слова "отъе...", то есть "отстань".

Comment: А какие сложности в правописании этого слова?

Comment: Предложите свой вариант ответа, иначе вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет значения. Я бы на вашем месте вообще никогда бы-с такие слова не писал. И чего непонятного в его написании?

Answer (score 1):

Только по факту правописания — без особых объяснений (•• — вместо букв):

••ать (инфинитив) — ••и (повелительное наклонение, или императив);
••аться — ••ись;
[отъ••аться](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) — отъ••ись.

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса русского языка

*— Отъ••ись от слепошарого бегом! — распорядился какой-то широкоплечий в кожаном камуфляже* (Андрей Лазарчук, Михаил Успенский. Посмотри в глаза чудовищ).

*Давили даже на Бродского, чтобы он публично отмежевался от «Романа с эпиграфами»; он этого делать не стал, а одному из питерских ходатаев ответил с присущей ему лапидарностью: «Отъ••ись!»* (Владимир Соловьев. Три еврея, или Утешение в слезах. Роман с эпиграфами).

[Слепошарый (разг.) —  близорукий, подслеповатый, рассеянный, невнимательный.]

Д о п о л н е н и е

А **сложность**, скорее всего, связана с правильным склонением и использованием постфиксов **-сь** и **-ся** (*отъ••айся* — неверно).
Очень похожее слово ведь склоняется совсем по-другому (•• — сн):
••ошать — ••ошай; ••ошаться — ••ошайся; от••ошаться — от••ошайся.

P. S. Приношу всем извинения! Ответ подкорректирован и дополнен.
P. P. S. Нацкорпус русского языка не просит подтвердить возраст пользователя. Если в поле поиска "слово или фраза" набрать слово *камуфляж* или *лапидарность*, то предложения, которые я использовала в качестве примеров, благополучно появятся.

Comment: А это уже отменили? https://www.kavicom.ru/news-view-11744.html  А это точка зрения: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424318/Сокрытие-точками-ненормативной-лексики ЧТО ТЕПЕРЬ ПРАВИЛЬНО? Я хотя бы за отточие.

Comment: Или должно быть возрастное ограничение, оно у нас есть? Или тематика должна быть отдельной. Меня от такой откровенной графики тошнит, а другим она очень даже нравится.  Поэтому и был задан такой "трудный" вопрос: правил не знаем, а матерные слова писать хотим.  А скорее всего,  хотим что-то еще... Давайте искать компромиссное решение. Если нельзя запретить, то нужно хотя бы морально уважать друг друга.

Comment: В вопросе и то поставили точки, да и все нормальные люди так делают. Просто уважают друг друга.  https://www.bfm.ru/news/488227  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=213212

Comment: Все так говорят, кто бы спорил. Осталось еще детский сад, ясельную группу охватить. Да и  я не лучше других, привыкла, что выделяться-то. Но писать-то зачем?

Comment: @Sharon, я понимаю, может, кому-то неприятно, да и закон вроде бы есть. Но надо учитывать и коммуникативную ситуацию . Здесь не ругаются, а изучают тему нецензурных слов. Здесь все же сайт лингвистов,филологов.

Comment: Поставьте отточие хотя бы, лингвисты-филологи. Это трудно сделать? Нетрудно, но без точек пишется – напоказ, с вызовом. Изучаем, мол, родную речь. Имеем право. Честно говоря,  у меня какое-то особое восприятие такой речи.  Я чувствую в ней особенный негатив, какую-то классовую озлобленность, агрессию. неприятие культуры в целом. В письменном варианте это особенно заметно.

Answer (score 1):

На лицо следующая закономерность:

```
отъезжать, отъесться // от - приставка, пишем твердый знак 
отелиться, отекать   // о - приставка, не пишем твердый знак
```

[см также](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)